# Compute the distribution of $S_\tau$

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

With $X_i$ i.i.d. random variables, with $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=1/2=\mathbb{P}(X_i=-1)$. $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Now given $a<0<b$ integers, the martingale $S_n$ stops at time:
$$\tau=\inf\{k\geq1:S_k\in\{a,b\}\}$$

I need to calculate the distribution of $S_\tau$,
can someone help me with this? I know that the chance that $a$ gets hit before $b$ is $\frac{b}{a+b}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hitting $a$ before $b$ means that $S_{\tau}=a$. Since you already know that the probability for this event is $b/(a+b)$, we have

$$\mathbb{P}(S_{\tau} = a)= \frac{b}{a+b}.$$

On the other hand, we also know that $\mathbb{P}(S_{\tau} \in \{a,b\})=1$. Hence,

$$\mathbb{P}(S_{\tau}=b) = 1- \mathbb{P}(S_{\tau}=a) = \frac{a}{a+b}.$$

Consequently, the distribution of $S_{\tau}$ is given by

$$\frac{b}{a+b} \delta_a + \frac{a}{a+b} \delta_b$$

where $\delta_x$ denotes the Dirac measure at $x$.